# Convert pre-written PHP form redirect after POST to Pop-Up message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am not a PHP person, but require to use a PHP mailer function to submit a simple contact form. I have managed to get the form working but after submission instead of redirecting to a URL `mailer.php`. I would like a simple pop-up box (not an alert) displaying a thankyou message, that the user can simply close and be returned to the previous page.

My html form is:

```
<div id="form-messages"></div>
<form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Your Number" required>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <button type="submit">Kilt outfit details</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My mailer.php contains:

```
<?php

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $tel = strip_tags(trim($_POST["tel"]));

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if (empty($name) or empty($tel)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "myemail@domain.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "Callback Request from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Phone Number: $tel\n\n";
    //$email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    //$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
    $email_headers = "From: $name <'callback@mydomain.co.uk'>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

And my JS file contains:

```
$(function () {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // TODO: The rest of the code will go here...
});

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function (event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

    // TODO
});

// Serialize the form data.
var formData = $(form).serialize();

// Submit the form using AJAX.
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })

    .done(function (response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#tel').val('');
    })

    .fail(function (data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });
```

I just don't understand enough to change the redirect to a popup, I have looked through past posts but cannot decipher what I need to change direction. I'd like for the form to pop up (i'd like to style it also with CSS) with an OK button that closes the popup.

Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: In this code, `event.preventDefault();` prevent redirect to `mailer.php` , and you can show any success msg in `.done(function(response) {` , i recommend use `SweetAlert` plugin to show your success msg or bootstrap modal.

Comment: lol i just did the same @pedram, and then read your comments and got puzzled that should i delete my solution :D

Comment: can you mark the answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes,

- First of all, move the section of `ajax` call inside the `submit` handler for your `contact form`
- For adding a message box use [Sweet Alert](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/) include the `css` and `js` files before you include your `JS` file given above you can use this [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/sweetalert) link,

your `JS` file will look like following in the end

```
$(function () {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function (event) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        event.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(form).attr('action'),
                data: formData
            })

            .done(function (response) {
                // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
                $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
                $(formMessages).addClass('success');

                swal({
                    title: 'Form Submitted',
                    text: response,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Close!'
                });

                // Clear the form.
                $('#name').val('');
                $('#tel').val('');
            })

            .fail(function (data) {
                // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
                $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
                $(formMessages).addClass('error');
                var msg = '';

                // Set the message text.
                if (data.responseText !== '') {

                    msg = data.responseText;
                } else {
                    msg = 'Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.';
                }

                swal({
                    title: 'Form Submitted',
                    text: msg,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Close!'
                });
            });
    });
});
```